# How do I get images from a big byte array file in an efficient way?

Tags: java, android, performance, multipart

Ok, so I'm making an android app that receives a big byte file (Multipart/mixed type around 100 MB) that contains multiple PNGs. I want to split the file in byte arrays so I can store each array to the corresponding user object.

This is a sample of the file I'm getting:

```
--d9883f5d-2811-40b9-a635-1493f807f371
Content-Location: http://something.com/id/00001/
Content-Type: image/png

âPNG


IHDR†»‡
...
...
...
r˚º˝   ¯ﬁ˛¸o˛É∑?ˇ¡€üÄˇ‡ÌO¿ˆ'‡?x˚º˝   ¯ﬁ˛¸o˛É∑?ˇ¡€üÄˇ‡ÌO¿F”È/ø„œˆákt:˝ˇø=s—æsêIENDÆB`Ç
--c967ed34-6e3a-4d34-9dae-bb7bb81c4138
Content-Location: http://something.com/id/00002/
Content-Type: image/png

âPNG


IHDR†»‡
...
...
...
r˚º˝   ¯ﬁ˛¸o˛É∑?ˇ¡€üÄˇ‡ÌO¿ˆ'‡?x˚º˝   ¯ﬁ˛¸o˛É∑?ˇ¡€üÄˇ‡ÌO¿F”È/ø„œˆákt:˝ˇø=s—æsêIENDÆB`Ç
--c967ed34-6e3a-4d34-9dae-bb7bb81c4138
```

One way I achieved the image extraction was with a Scanner, but it worked only on android lollipop and above, on kitkat I got an OutOfMemoryError. Here's the code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=Content-Location.+?\\n+)", Pattern.UNIX_LINES);
scanner = new Scanner(fis, "x-MacRoman");
scanner.useDelimiter(pattern);
scanner.next();
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
  String nextBm = scanner.next();
  String pictureId = nextBm.split("/")[4];
  String pictureSubString = nextBm.substring(nextBm.indexOf("PNG") - 1);
  FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(context.getFilesDir().toString() + "/" + pictureId));
  os.write(pictureSubString.getBytes("x-MacRoman"));
  os.close();
}
```

Then I tried using a BufferedStreamReader but the problem was that when I called the method readLine() there was no way to know if the line break consisted of a carriage return, a line feed, or both so the bytes never got decoded.

The method I'm using now is highly inefficient: I read the file byte by byte with a FileInputStream looking for the start and end of the PNG. This gets some images skipped and takes a long time.

Any ideas on how to get the images? I don't know if there's an easier way to do this that I'm not aware of.

Comment: from where are you getting these images? Did you try Picasso with url of image?

Comment: The problem is that this file contains the bytes of all the pictures from a database, Picasso would help me if the url was for a single image as far as I know.